# Read hierarchy, type and occurence out of XSD-File

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

i want to read the hierarchies, types and occurences out of a XSD-File.
Until now i have only succeded importing the file into an XmlSchemaSet Object, from which i still cannot read the string/int/bool types, neither the max/min occurences or hierarchies.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema 
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>

  <xs:simpleType name="ActionType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="GET"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="POST"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="Data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="Action" type="ActionType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Target" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Parameters" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="include_entities" maxOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="include_user_entities" maxOccurs="0" />
          <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: An XML schema is _itself_ an XML document - could you read it into an `XDocument` and query for the items you want?

Comment: it may be possible, however what i want is actually importing the whole XSD to a C# Object, so that i can get as example:
Data Data with Enumeration Action Type, string Target, and so on

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the XSD tool from Microsoft. Save the XSD as XML format and run the XSD tool with the following command:

```
  xsd file.xml /c
```

It will generate serializable objects for you. Then you could use:

```
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(XmlClassTypeYouCreatedOnXsdTool);
  XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xml);
  var instance = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Remember to start the Visual Studio command prompt in order to have the XSD path set, otherwise you won't be able to find it.

Comment: can i generate XmlClassTypeYouCreatedOnXsdTool on runtime?

Comment: XSD tool creates a strongly typed class for you to serialize any XML (in you case, a XSD which is also in XML format) in memory at runtime. You could try creating your own time at runtime using Reflection, but I don't see the point of it. You need to serialize XSD files or XML files? I believe I still haven't figured out the whole picture of your question.